# Call inferSchema directly after the load is done with spark-csv

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way that I can directly call inferSchema after load is done?

Ex:

```scala
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
                  option("header", "true").
                  option("inferSchema", "false").load(location)
df.schema
```

I want to call some thing like below:

```scala
val newdf = df.inferSchema()
newdf.printSchema()
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not possible** unless you define a new schema and apply it to the new `DataFrame` on creation.

You can also read the schema from using the `csv` source and store it to use afterwards but this will scan the data either way.

You haven't inferred a schema, `spark-csv` considers every column as a string.

Comment: 3.0+ - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2d01bccbd4c93bfbfa1a9e618fcb795b7106f01c/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L3802-L3827